# Rspec/Capybara - change should into expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

In my Ruby on Rails 4.2 app, I would like to change a test checking inline style to the rspec 3 more recent "expect" on a "should" but i get an error.

When I use the test below, my test passes:

```
find('#zone')['style'].should == "background-image: url(xxxxx); background-size: cover;"
```

I tried to convert it to rspec more recent "expect"

```
expect('#zone')['style'].to eq("background-image: url(xxxxx); background-size: cover;")
```

but I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for #<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x00000008578840>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expect(find('#zone')['style']).to eq "background-image...."
```

In general, `something.should ==` is equivalent to writing `expect(something).to eq`

There are some subtle differences ("bug fixes", if you like) on objects that use delegated methods, or implement methods such as `should` themselves; but for the most part I wouldn't worry about that; you can consider the two formats equivalent, but should always aim to use the new `expect` format.

One other nice conversion is that if you wrote tests that use the (sometimes *implicitly* defined) `subject` variable - e.g. `subject.should ...`, you can re-write this as either: `expect(subject).to`, or alternatively just: `is_expected.to`

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer is technically correct, it can potentially lead to flaky tests if you have a dynamic page.  This can happen when the element where the `style` attribute is being checked is being updated due to a JS action, and the check can occur before the style has changed.  It's much better to write the expectation as

```
expect(page).to have_css('#zone[style="background-image: url(xxxxx); background-size: cover;"]')
```

or

```
expect(find('#zone')).to match_css('[style="background-image: url(xxxxx); background-size: cover;"]')
```

Comment: by the way i never saw this match_css, is there any difference with have_css ?

Comment: @Mathieu `have_css` will find matching descendant elements of the current scope element,  `match_css` checks if the current scope element would be matched by the passed css selector

Comment: This is very helpful when there are certain animations still happening in the style of the element. I've found that flaky tests can happen when interacting with something in the DOM that's still animating, so this was super helpful to add another check.

Comment: I do kind of wish Capybara was capable of handling these type of things in the DOM though. Sometimes it feels like things go "too fast" which requires me to write more expectations to "slow things down" so to speak.

Comment: @Phil Capybara only knows how to do what you tell it -- It has no way of knowing that an element is animating via CSS or JS, and is working through the webdriver abstraction layer and the browser event queue so it has no control over exactly when an interaction (click for example) would actually occur. You're much better off just disabling animation during testing if possible (Capybara has some support to attempt to do that if you're letting it run the AUT and you enable it). If your app is written in such a way that animation can't be disabled then you have to verify ready state.